# Scripting Language Evolution

Tags: shell-script, scripting, application

I have an assignment due Monday and I need some help because I have no knowledge on the subject and can't even understand what to search exactly. I am not waiting for an essay or something just some guidance or some links.

"You are to write a paper on the evolution of server-side technologies used for writing Web
applications since the early days of the Web to the present day. Your paper is expected to focus on the following areas:

How scripting languages have evolved, providing code examples. You should highlight the
changes that you consider the most significant for application developers and provide
analysis as to why you have selected them."

As I understand it, I have to mention shell scripting and its evolution and other languages that have evolve.. I am not sure.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I will not be very verbose, but the first dynamic page was made with cgi script (they could be either in c in shell bash...) then someone invented php which is a scripting language and then you have now real application that you compile before publishing on the web (IIS and .Net, Java and tomcat for example)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems to the extent laid out in the [Help Center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Here you're expected to do [some](http://royal.pingdom.com/2007/12/07/a-history-of-the-dynamic-web/) [research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) _before_ asking. If you're unsure regarding an assignment, _you should ask the course instructor_.

Comment: It might be construed as on topic in so far as it fits better here than it would on, e.g., S.O., Serverfault, Superuser, etc.  So either there is no appropriate S.E. site for a question such as this (which seems ridiculous) or it might as well be here.  These are technologies, after all, which evolved *primarily* on *nix platforms.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' I agree that the topic is probably more relevant to U&L than to SO or SF. However, while we should appreciate the OP being forthcoming regarding the Q being about a homework assignment, as the question is phrased now, in my opinion, it is more about the assignment itself, rather than the technologies. If it is indeed so, I believe it would be in the _OPs best interest_ to consult the course staff directly. Assuming this is part of University-level studies, learning how to search for information regarding unfamiliar topics is a _key skill_ that's worth learning.

Comment: @ThomasNyman Yeah, s/he should definitely start with the instructor if the question is "What does this question mean"?

Comment: [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be a good site for this question; perhaps [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

The term ["scripting language"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language) is now-a-days really an ambiguous, wishy-washy, or just plain prejudicial one, but a discussion of how that came to be is a discussion of the evolution of the languages to which the label is often applied.

Originally, *scripting* referred to languages whose source was interpreted at runtime instead of compiled (e.g., shells such as bash), but it came to be applied to languages like python and perl, which are (at least in their present day incarnations) pre-compiled into [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_code) then executed.  The ambiguity here is that other languages such as java work the same way, but no one refers to java as "a scripting language".

The reason these got lumped in with the shell (the original "scripting language", I believe) is likely because they tended to be at least an order of magnitude slower than purely compiled languages, and so before we had computers so fast this difference was made somewhat irrelevant in a wider range of contexts, they were mostly just used for running short, single source file "scripts".  This would also be fair to say of most dynamic web stuff up until 12-15 years ago -- most of it just used short CGI *scripts* with a smidgeon of (often inlined/embedded) javascript (a further ambiguity: java*script* is usually left out of the "scripting language" category because it is not general purpose).

So, when discussing what's colloquially (or prejudicially) referred to as the  mainstream "scripting languages" server side today, it probably makes more sense to use the term **dynamically typed object oriented languages** (you could throw in "general purpose" or "server side" to exclude javascript, which is also object oriented and dynamically typed).  These include:

- Perl
- Python
- PHP
- Ruby

They are distinguished from other common server side technologies such Java and C# by the fact that they use [dynamic](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DynamicTyping) instead of static typing, and that, again, is why what is usually meant by "scripting" language in the context of web technology is really **dynamically typed object oriented** language (which certainly does include javascript, if we leave out "server side").  The irony here is that this excludes non-OO languages such as shell, but shell is no longer used much in web programming anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to focus on architectures, as well as specific languages:

- CGI
- [web application frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework)
- the rise of open source software, such as the Apache HTTP server
- browser wars that led to the evolution of JavaScript as a mature programming language

Comment: Why _the rise_? The first HTTP servers were opensource and [opensource HTTP servers have always been predominant](http://news.netcraft.com/archives/category/web-server-survey/).